# AWS. Перенаправление с S3 на EC2

Tags: proxy, redirect, amazon-web-services, ec2

Есть статический сайт в S3, например, `example.com`.

Необходимо при запросе `example.com/test` перенаправить запрос на отдельное приложение, поднятое в EC2 инстансе с DNS `test.example.com`.

Могу ли я такое перенаправление организовать штатными средствами AWS?

Редирект через правила бакета не сработал:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
  <KeyPrefixEquals>test/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>test.example.com</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: Редирект со статической страницы средствами HTML или JavaScript вам не подходит?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: Возможно, для внешнего URL требуется указать http:// test.example.com  По данному туториалу ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html ) пробовали настраивать?

Comment: Да, я настраивал по этой статье. Вариант с http не помог.